# Why is getConfiguration occasionally throwing File cannot be null?

Tags: java

This might seem to be a simple question (if that's the case, please excuse me), but after 20 minutes of online searching I did not find any sensible answer.

I have several cron jobs to be executed via `QuartzRunner`, let's call the first `FooBean` and the second `BarBean` for now. `FooBean` is running daily at 00:00 for 6 (!) hours and sometimes it is not executed properly. After carefully studying the logs I found out that `FooBean` fails to execute when `BarBean` fails to execute. `BarBean` is executed daily at 03:00 and sometimes it throws:

```
 22866 java.lang.NullPointerException: File cannot be <null>
 22867     at org.jconfig.FileWatcher.<init>(FileWatcher.java:54)
 22868     at org.jconfig.handler.AbstractHandler.addFileListener(AbstractHandler.java:39)
 22869     at org.jconfig.ConfigurationManager.addFileListener(ConfigurationManager.java:180)
 22870     at org.jconfig.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:122)
```

sometimes it does not throw it and then `FooBean` is executed properly. If `BarBean` fails, then the log shows some Transaction deadlock issue repeatedly for ten minutes and then JDBC connection failures repeated again and again for almost three hours. I do not understand what file is being involved. The line throwing the error looks like:

```
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration("inventory");
```

and `org.jconfig` namespaces are involved here. Intuitively this seems to be a misconfiguration, but I did not find any sources which explain the issue.

Comment: First of all there are two different Problems. First one sounds like, FooBean locks your Database and if BarBean runs at 03:00 there could be some type of circular wait. This would then lead to a Deadlock. The second Problem is your NullPointer. This could have many Reasons and without seeing the code it is very hard to find it.

Comment: @kSp the relevant part of the code was included into the question. I know what a NullPointerException is, the question is why can ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration throw such an exception. My question does not ask about transactional deadlocks, it gives that information as a context of how one cron job's error affects the other cron job. I am convinced that a reader who pays attention while reading will find the source-code line in the question.

Comment: I thought your Deadlock could lead to the Nullpointer as result of a timing problem (something like transaction which containing your filename was not commited or something like that, because of that i mentioned it in relation to that i didn't recognized the one liner as the code). Ok I've looked at the code from org.jconfig and first question that i've got is did you created the config file which you are trying to read? Where is the file located? Is it maybe on your Classpath?

Comment: And anyway, it has something to do with your Deadlock otherwise it would not work properly if deadlock is not appearing. So this is necessary!

Comment: @kSp I have no knowledge about org.jfconfig whatsoever. This question is an attempt to find out whether this is common knowledge. If so, then I can use it for my project. Otherwise I will do a deep analysis and answer this question myself. So, in short I do not know what file should I have. It seems that a file is missing, but I don't know what and where that should be. This error occurs before the deadlock and due to the information I have seen from the logs I'm pretty sure this is a possible cause of the deadlock.

Comment: Ok, The ConfigurationManagers getConfiguration-Method tries to load a config file from your classpath. The function will look if configuration is already loaded or it should be loaded based on parameterized name. If it should be loaded it concatenates the name with '_config.xml' which leads to filename 'inventory_config.xml' in your case. This file should be available on Classpath as jconfig tries to load it from there.

Comment: @kSp I do not have time to test this at this point, but this sounds perfectly reasonable. If you convert this into an answer, I will accept it after I try this out and find it to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ConfigurationManagers getConfiguration-Method tries to load a config file from your classpath. The function concatenates the given name with '_config.xml'.
In your case this would be 'inventory_config.xml' this file should be in available on your classpath (main/resources) because ConfigurationManager tries to load it from there.